# How do you add variables in a Word Template?

Tags: microsoft-word

For example, I'd like to be able to define company_name somewhere, and in the document have [company_name] and the pre-defined value will be displayed.

Is this a feature that Word has?

Comment: Yes.  Check the Word help for {fields}.

Comment: There are various ways you can introduce Variables in Word. Although it doesn't directly answer your question, see my response to http://superuser.com/questions/595727/how-to-find-document-variables-in-ms-word-without-using-a-macro/596010#596010