# Customize existing MS Word Template document's variables & Content Controls

Tags: microsoft-word, xml, templates

I'm looking to adapt [this official MS-Word Template document](https://templates.office.com/en-us/Statement-of-Work-Red-design-TM03923594) to our company's needs, but I can't locate the source for the variables-in place and how they're managed.

[image: Here's an example Content-Control, the red '000', that has no data on how it was mapped.]

[This was a great read](https://superuser.com/questions/595727/how-to-find-document-variables-in-ms-word-without-using-a-macro?newreg=bd6168aa037341c5bf1d0663f847269d) but I still can't find where and how the variables on this document are sourced and linked together. 'alt-F9' shows me the existing document-field code implementations, but I believe these are mapped XML schemas that aren't discernable from the MS word user interface. How do I view and edit the existing mapped XML schemas? (If that is what they are)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What you are asking could be the subject of a book.

Normally here we try to give answers but not write books. Content Controls can be linked or *mapped* to XML nodes but are not required to be so linked. The key through the user Interface is the [Developer Tab](http://addbalance.com/word/developertab.htm) and possibly the "document properties" found under Insert > Quick Parts which are discussed in the second reference link below.

[That template](https://templates.office.com/en-us/Statement-of-Work-Red-design-TM03923594) could definitely be improved by using mapped content controls for information that is entered in multiple places. One of these could also be used to have the client name and other information in the footer or header.

Here are some references:

- [Word Content Controls](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/content_controls.html) by Greg Maxey
- [Repeating Data Using Document Property Content Controls and other Mapped Controls](http://addbalance.com/word/MappedControls.htm#PageStart) (my page)
- [Mapped Content Controls](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/mapped_content_controls.html) by Greg Maxey
- [Content Controls](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/word/content-controls-in-word) - Microsoft Documentation - focus is on changes made with Word 2013
- [Walkthrough: Bind content controls to custom XML parts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-binding-content-controls-to-custom-xml-parts?view=vs-2022) - Microsoft Documentation *(requires Visual Studio)*
- [How to Add custom XML parts to document-level customizations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-add-custom-xml-parts-to-document-level-customizations?view=vs-2022) - Microsoft Documentation *(requires Visual Studio)*
- [Custom XML parts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/custom-xml-parts-overview?view=vs-2022) - Microsoft Documentation *(requires Visual Studio)*

I recommend starting with the first three unless you are already into VSTO solutions. They show how to work through the user interface of Word rather than external coding.

Here are free Add-Ins that make mapping Content Controls relatively simple. They are from Greg Maxey and Graham Mayor.

- [Insert Content Control Add-In](https://www.gmayor.com/insert_content_control_addin.htm) by Graham Mayor
- [Content Control Tools](http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/content_control_tools.html) by Greg Maxey
- (probably more than you need) [CC/V/BM & DP Tools Add-In](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/cc_var_bm_doc_prop_tools_addin.html) by Greg Maxey *Content Control / Document Variable / Bookmark and Document Property Editor Add-In)*

### Other Thoughts

In your question, you are conflating variables, fields, and Content Controls. My answer deals with Content Controls, which are not fields and which can relate to variable information. Here is a [list of the usual Word Fields](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/field-codes-in-word-HA102110133.aspx) with links to documentation. Document Properties can also hold variable information which can be shown in a DocProperty Field. These document properties are different, though from the ones discussed in my article and are not linked or mapped to XML.

### Work on Content Controls through the User Interface is best done using the Windows desktop application

The Macintosh interface currently does not encompass creation or modification of Content Controls. It can be done through vba, though. At some point this may change but it has been more than ten years waiting for Microsoft to add this to their Mac versions. (March 2022) [Content Controls for the Mac OS](https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2019/08/content-controls-for-macos-cool-code/) by John Korchok

Comment: I think I'm going to have to go down the XML variable rabbit hole with Visual studio. I was hoping that Microsoft's official default templates wouldn't require any serious under-the-hood work, but it looks like that's how the document was built. Thank you.

Comment: Please look at my edited answer. I've provided links to three free utilities for Mapping Content Controls without you needing to delve into the XML. There are more on Greg Maxey's site linked from his main page about Content Controls.